# Mosfets as a switch for batteries in series

Tags: batteries, mosfet, battery-charging

I am contemplating a way to build a new battery pack for a project that I am working on. However I think that I have run into a problem, but I am not sure.

I have a battery pack with about 27 batteries in series and 15 strings in parallel, as seen in the picture below (just a small sample), My goal, is to isolate (at least down to a small leakage current) a single battery in the pack in case it falls out of safe operating range.

[image]

I am thinking about using N-channel mosfets for this job, but I don't know how well they will work in this type of circuit.

Will this work? If not, what would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- why do you want to switch both legs? Switching a single leg is sufficient to block all current.
- You do know that power MOSFETs have a 'body diode'?
- Have you thought about how you want to produce the gate voltage to drive you MOSFET switches? A typical power MOSFET needs ~ 8V at its gate.
- I think your FETs are placed the wrong way round.

Summary: my answer would be that this probably is not going to work.

Comment: Yes you are correct, a single fet would work.
I did forget about the body diode, but using a ptype and a ntype fet could solve this problem.
I have a 12V supply that would be switching the fets.
My greater concern is I have always been told that you put Nfets at the bottom of a circuit, and Pfets at the top, or else they wont work properly. From that standpoint would this work?

Comment: That has to do with my 3d point: from where do you get your gate drive voltage? When you have an N FET as top switch, you need a voltage ~ 8V *above* the positive rail.

Comment: Oh...I didn't know that. Now that makes more sense. And what do you mean by the wrong way arround?

Comment: One more thing. What would work?

Comment: Relays certainly would, but those are quite wasteful in terms of space and current usage. You could also put a fuse in series with each those batteries and create an appropriately placed short circuit when you want to disconnect a battery.

Comment: @Reid: For a N MOSFET the voltage at the drain must be more positive than the source (=inbound arrow).

Comment: @Reid: oops, your used a strange (at least for me) symbol for your FET. You call it an IRF530, better check the datasheet for the symbol for that part, to make it clear how yyou want to connect the FETs.

Comment: @Wouter I think I am going to go with solid state relays (which brings on more questions asked here:http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/64486/help-with-picking-solid-state-relay)

Answer (score 1):

MOSFET is a transistor. It will have P-channel and N-channel. It consists of a source, gate and drain. Read the concept [MOSFET as Switch](http://www.edgefxedu.in/mosfet-as-a-switch-circuit-diagram-free-circuits/) to get good idea about it.
I read that post few days back and it has given small idea about this concept. So, I am sharing that link with you. If you are interested then you may visit that page.